# How to get music to replay in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

After my song (music.mp3) ends, it doesn't replay. I have the following code:

```
# import pygame and other code
pygame.mixer.music.load('music.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play()
pygame.mixer.music.rewind()
pygame.init()
```

Shouldn't it be replaying itself? And if not, how do I make it replay whenever it ends?

Comment: Probably has something to do with the `init()` call at the end resetting everything.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not do what you think it does.  It starts playing the MP3 but the `play()` call doesn't wait until the file is played, it *immediately* returns, playing the music asynchronously.  So starting a song and immediately rewinding in the next line of code does not make any sense.  If you want the music to play more than once, have a look at the `loop` argument of [pygame.mixer.music.play()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.play).  It allows to play the music a given number of times or indefinitely.

Comment: Yeah i actually figured this out last night, but thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

The play function takes an integer number of times to play the sound. -1 sets it to infinite.

```
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
```

EDIT:
It's proper practice to initiate pygame before setting up the mixer, as pygame.init() also calls pygame.mixer.init().